# Class inheritance and upcasting in c++

Tags: c++, oop

This is the simple code I am dealing with to learn about inheritance down casting and up casting etc.

```
class A
{ public:
  void p() {cout << “A::p\n”;}
  virtual void q() {cout << “A::q\n”;}
};

class B : public A
{ public:
  void p() { cout << “B::p\n”;}
  void q() { cout << “B::q\n”;}
};

int main()
{ A* a1 = new B;
  a1 -> p();
  a1 -> q();
}
```

Following was my expected output

```
B::p
B::q
```

Following is the actual output

```
A::p
B::q
```

My understanding is that the class B is inheriting class A. Then in the main we create a Pointer to class A and set its reference to B. Therefore when we call function p() and q() I expected whatever was inside class B to print.

Can anyone please clarify my misunderstanding here?

Comment: You are calling a non-virtual method on a base class pointer - why do you expect an override from a derived class to get called? That's precisely what `virtual` is for - which `A::p` isn't.

Comment: Where exactly are you upcasting anything?

Comment: @Blindy: in `A* a1 = new B;`. A cast from pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base (whether implicit or otherwise) is often colloquially referred to as an "upcast" (because you are casting "up" the inheritance hierarchy.) The reverse - always explicit - cast is then a "downcast".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice the difference between the two methods is that one is marked `virtual` on the base class `A`, the other isn't:

Method q is defined as

```
virtual void q()
```

On the base class, whereas p is just

```
void p()
```

Hence,

```
A* a1 = new B;
a1 -> p(); ... Uses a1's type to determine the method, statically
a1 -> q(); ... Uses virtual method table to determine the method at run time
```